# Cloud Firestore : How to select where value not in array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Consider that I store users to follow in a list, then later I want to suggest users to another user, so they can follow. This user already has followers they are following, so first thing I want to do is exclude a list of users that this user is already following from the query.

Considering that Firestore has a `WHERE` clause, would it be possible to ignore a list of UIDs using `WHERE`, you know, something that would work like `SQL NOT IN()`, or otherwise any other way?

```
const userIAlreadyFollow = ['uid1', 'uid2'];
userToFollowRef.where("uid", "!==", userIAlreadyFollow);
```

Please consider that the `userIAlreadyFollow` can get pretty big.

I would get users to follows without queries, then filter through that using a normal javascript, but then the returned list might have all the users/most of the users this user is already following, then would require another query to try again, just feels like a hack.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried already? And do you have a problem with the not equal part or the multiple where part?

Answer (score 3):

Firestore currently doesn't support anything like SQL "where in" or "where not in" queries.  You have to know what you're looking for, and it has to be indexed.  There is also currently no inequality searches.

See [Firestore query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) for more information about what's not supported.